# Result Set to multiple variables

Tags: ssis

I am running that uses multiple Foreach Loop Containers and want to run them simultaneously. However, I get the error message -

> COM error object information is available.  Source:
>   "ADODB.Recordset"  error code: 0x800A0BCD  Description: "Either BOF or
>   EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested
>   operation requires a current record."

Obviously, once one Foreach Loop process completes the result set gets dropped.

To get around this I assumed you can pass the same data to different variables like so -

[image: variable mapping]

Then in each of the loops just change the DBList, with one Foreach Loop being DBList and the other DBList2 -

[image: For loop results set]

However, I receive the error message -

> There is an invalid number of result bindings returned for the
>   ResultSetType: "ResultSetType_Rowset".

Is it impossible to run multiple Foreach Loops concurrently?

Comment: The short answer is "No, it is not impossible", but there are some catches. First, which environment are you using for SSIS development? And which version of SQL Server are you targeting?

Comment: I'm not sure assigning the same result set to two different variables like that will work. What should work, however, is assigning one variable value to the other, after your `Execute SQL Task`. But how you do that will depend on your answers to my first two questions.

Comment: @digital.aaron firstly cheers for taking a look. For SSIS I am using Visual Studio Pro 2017 and targeting  SQL Server 2017.

Comment: To answer your question, you can run multiple foreach loops concurrently, but not the way you are attempting to. You want a data flow, using multicast into 2 different object type variables.  Then configure each of the foreach loops and you will need separate variables to use in the variable mappings of each of the loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run foreach loops concurrently, but you have to get your resultset into multiple object type variables and you also have to have 2 sets of variables you would use for the variable mappings for each of the foreach loops.

Example:

[image]

Your data flow will consist of a source, multicast and 2 different RecordSet destinations:

[image]

The example source here is just returning 1 column of a list of numbers.  We multiple cast that into 2 separate RecordSet Destinations that are then assigned to their own object variable type.  In this example I have 2 variables, User::RecordSet1 and User:RecordSet2.

Then each of the foreach loops is configured to each of those variables:

[image]

Then you have separate variables for each of the foreach loops:

[image]

From there you'll need to make sure you're using the appropriate set of variables in whatever code you have in each of the foreach loops.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an `Execute SQL Task`, create a `Data Flow`, and then use a SQL Query as your Source (probably OLE DB Source). Then pipe that to a `Multicast`, with outputs to two different `Recordset Destinations`.  In the `Component Properties` tab, set the VariableName to one of your object variables, then click on the `Input Columns` to choose which columns you want to include. Do the same for the other `Recordset Destination`, choosing your second object variable this time, and again selecting which columns to include. Then go back to your `Control Flow` and link the `Data Flow` you just created to your two `Foreach Loop Container`.

[image]

[image]